# CSS "spriting" the content of a stylesheet?

Tags: css

This isn't something I think exists, but it would always be interesting to see if this is possible. I was curious as to whether or not I could split up a stylesheet and call certain parts of it. For example:

```
.style { color: red; }
.second-style { color: green; }
```

Sorry about how poorly worded this question was before. What I'm trying to say is that I want one large CSS file with all the rules I need, so I only have to load one stylesheet. I understand the whole thing will be read, but I was wondering if there was a way to select just some parts of it. For instance, if I wanted `.style` to apply on one browser, I could select just the first line. If I only wanted `.second-style`, then I could select the second line. Similarly to how an image sprites only select a certain selection of the image to minimize HTTP requests.

Hope this question makes more sense now.

**EDIT** Another reason why I want such an option is also to manage IE conditional comments, as more and more clients ask for browser compatibility.

Comment: What benefit do you think this would bring? How would you actually use it? To get all of the styles associated with a selector, you need to parse the entire stylesheet. Don't get me wrong, this is a good question, but I'm just curious.

Comment: Are you talking about splitting up a CSS file per page? I'm a little confused on what you're asking.

Comment: uhh, doesn't having all your css in one sheet keep the number of http requests to a solid 1?

Comment: to address your edit, you can use IE conditional comments to add a class to the `<html>` tag, and within your stylesheet use that to target those browsers. i.e. `.ie7 p {color: red} p {color: blue}`

Comment: If you concatenate your style sheet, this really shouldn't be a problem. There is really no reason your style sheet should ever be so large that this should matter. You can definitely only call certain style sheets on certain pages, but you are going to have extra http requests for each one. The thought lately is to concatenate and minify your css and your .js into one file each and just get it out of the way in 2 requests.

Comment: Let's say I'm making a site, but something isn't supported in earlier browsers. I don't want to have another request to another file using conditional tags let's say, as that'd increase my HTTPWebRequest count. But I don't always want those styles to affect the DOM, so I can't have it in one file. Therefore I'd like to select from one CSS file a certain selection of lines to style, and to disclude the other styles, like how sprite images select only a portion of the image. Is that possible is what I'm asking?

Comment: If you're really having problems with this kinda thing you should prehaps check out "Object Oriented CSS" or one of the other various CSS methodologies, and perhaps a preprocessor like LESS, SASS, or Stylus

Comment: Please comment when you downvote... It helps us newbies know how to correctly ask questions on SO.

Comment: You already have some feedback up there. The question is a bit confusing and has clunky wording. Still don't know what "Where I could somehow state to style only using line 1" means...

Comment: Sorry about that, reworded the question.

Comment: @NickBull: Once you've minified your stylesheet, there's only one line anyways, so how will you select which parts of your stylesheet will apply to certain elements? Isn't that exactly what selectors are for?

Comment: What he's asking for is impossible, the answer is LESS, SASS, or Static/Dynamic Bundling. OOCSS is a plus but not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna have a look at LESS
http://lesscss.org/

Of course @import could help too, but LESS is way more flexible, as it not only helps you organize your css, but also supports variables and more.

What you can do with LESS is organize your styles into modules for example

```
typography.css
sprites.css
style1.css
style2.css
forms.css
..etc
```

This is mainly for organizational reasons, after which you can combine your modules to produce a single big CSS file that you can then use on you site.

Now lets say you want one file that uses style1 and typography ..so just create a less file called variant1.css that contains

```
@import "style1.css"
@import "typography.css"
```

And now variant1.css will contain the content of the 2 css files you listed

..tada: modules + recombination = choices

Comment: don't think that's really what OP is asking about; though honestly, I'm not even sure what that is.

Comment: Can you explain how this answers OP's question?

Comment: Well ..wait n see. He said split a css file to use certain parts. Calling class-a or class-b to me has nothing to do with splitting things up.

Comment: I think OP wants to selectively activate/deactivate specific parts of one master .css file. the `class-a` / `class-b` namespacing is probably as close as he can get to this specific goal.

Comment: No... I'm trying to minimize HTTP requests. If I had more than one stylesheet then I'd make multiple requests per sheet. I want to select parts of a stylesheet from one single stylesheet, similarly to how spriting works with images, where you select one part.

Comment: LESS will still work as it can combine files too. You can also use something like Yahoo YUI compressor, or better Google Closure compiler.

Comment: btw you can't select a specific part of a stylesheet like you would like. You have to create multiple small css files (modules), and then you can do something like href=styles.php?module1,module2 and have it compile the 2 modules into 1 css file.

Comment: Marked as the answer, because you've answered my question - it cannot be done. I guess modularity is the key to CSS, and SASS/LESS both look promising for the future of OOCSS. My assumption then from your comments is the number of requests can be solved through recombination, and the size of the requests through minification and removing unused rules. Thank you for your detailed comments! You're helping a newbie learn a lot quickly :)

Comment: Yes, hand tailored css via modules to limit both number of requests and final css size.There are many server plug ins that exist that allow you to do this dynamically too: select style sheets, combine them, minify them, and then serve them as one single file. Personally i just like doing it manually with preconfigured static output files.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're trying to accomplish...you could sort of achieve it by namespacing the CSS and then changing a class on your `<body>` element:

```
.classname-a .style { color: red; }

.classname-b .second-style { color: green; }

<body class="classname-a">
....
```

Not that I endorse doing that.

Comment: This is probably the best approach, and if you use modernizr you can use classes based on feature detection and style accordingly.

Comment: He's not trying to namespace. He basically wants to split the 2 classes into 2 specific files, "without" actually creating 2 files and being able to load just parts of the css file,  as to save bandwidth & http requests. Like href=style.css?load=section1 and it only returns half of the file ..yes i know, not possible unless you code something up. Dynamic bundling basically

Comment: Robert is right, I agree a lot can be done through thorough CSS refactoring and using selectors carefully, but that's not what the question is about. Thanks for the answer though, and also why don't you endorse doing that? It's not very readable, but as @nullability states, I see this done a lot - mostly by Modernizr or similar JS files. What's wrong with doing it past readability?

Answer (score 1):

Sprites are used to minimize the number of HTTP requests. By combining and minifying your CSS files, you essentially do the same thing, as you'll be serving a single CSS file which will get cached by the user's browser.

Also, instead of loading stylesheets with conditional comments, just add a class:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if lte IE 7]><html class="bad-ie" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]> <html class="good-ie" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> --> <html class="not-ie" lang="en"><!-- <![endif]-->
```

And target the browser within your stylesheet:

```
.bad-ie body {
    font-size: 100px;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't possible.  If I understand what you want though and it were possible, it wouldn't be very efficient since you would have to go through the whole CSS sheet to find what rules apply to each page when they load.

I would recommend that you have 2 CSS sheets per web page: one for the layout that is constant among all your webpages and one that is specific to that page.  This means that you will load the minimum amount of CSS possible, albeit you will have 2 HTTP requests.  If you are really worried about HTTP web requests, you could always just dump it all into one massive file, though I don't advise this, since it will be a PAIN to make any changes/find unnecessary rules from past dev cycles.

Comment: If you employ .scss files as partials this would not be an issue what so ever. I have 12 .scss files on a project currently. No style sheet goes past the fold and it is crazy easy to maintain. reset, variables, global, structure, type, color, individual modules, etc, etc --- then smash that all into one tight .css file and BAM! You will have a big smile on your face.

Comment: @nouveau Excactly what i was trying to explain to him. I know & you know it's what he wants, he just doesn't know it yet :) ..either that or dynamic bundling. Buts that more error prone than static bundling

Comment: Yep. I mean - it's great that @Nick_Bull - is thinking about this at least. I wonder sometimes about the ol styles in the head. In this line of thought, that would be even less http requests. However, if your CSS is that huge, you are really not taking the right approach. We have a HUGE project and I just checked the size of the CSS after we compressed it with codekit. It is 72k. It only loads once. That is half the size of one .jpg and only on .http request ---

Comment: "That is half the size of one .jpg and only ONE http request"